# Handle failover in gRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I use gRPC to communicate between Order service and Product service. I have one case need to help.

If Order service call method in Product service to save a data in Product service. But after save data in Product service and Product service send callback to Order service and Order service is failed and can't receive callback.

How can I against this case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a question about gRPC specifically but more about a pattern for handling distributed transactions. I suggest looking at the [saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) for this case.